# How to view django database on sqliteonline

Tags: django, database, sqlite, model

I want my database deployed on sqliteonline instead of django admin but i am stuck at how to do that. Thanks in advance. It will be of much help!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are keeping well.

I believe from my understanding that you are misinterpreting what `SQLITEONLINE` is. It is simply a web-based database IDE.

If you want to host your database remotely for Django, I would recommend changing from the Django default of `sqlite` as this is a database designed for local storage and not remote connectivity.

To change your database to a remote one, you could go to a SQL database and connect remotely by adjusting the settings in your `settings.py` file. See Django's documentation on the topic [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/).